# Not sure what is wrong with my XSL document, and my XML result doc is not redenering properly

Tags: xml, xslt, functional-programming

[DropBox link to XML file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awxrf8iu5g3fv32/congress.xml?dl=0) I have been working on this XSL document that is required to use functional programming, and even though it is error-free, the result document is not rendering properly and looks like pages and pages of only numbers and no text (it looks like machine code.).

The result should display the candidate names, votes, percentage of votes, the district and a bar chart equal to the length of votes. I keep messing with it  but nothing seems to change the appearance. Some parts that confuse me are: **the Global Variable that references the "candidates/candidate" nodeset; the cellCount parameter that is equal to the value of the "candidatePercent" variable MULTIPLIED by 100 and rounded to the nearest integer; among other things.**

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="candidateInfo"
     select="document('candidates.xml')/candidates/candidate" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</title>
            <link href="vwstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">
               <header>
                  <img src="vwlogo.png" alt="Voter Web" />
               </header>

               <h1>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</h1>

               <section id="votingResults">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="congressResults/district" />
               </section>

             </div>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="district">
      <h2>District <xsl:value-of select="@dNumber" /></h2>
      <table class="electionTable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Candidate</th>
               <th>Votes</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="candidates/candidate" />
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="candidate">
        <xsl:variable name="candidateVotes" select="sum(votes)" />
        <xsl:variable name="totalVotes" select="sum(..//votes" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidatePercent" select="sum($candidateVotes) div count($totalVotes)" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidateName" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/name" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidateParty" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/party" />
      <tr>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="$candidateName" />
            (<xsl:value-of select="$candidateParty" />)
        </th>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(candidateVotes, '###,##0')" />
            (<xsl:value-of  select="format-number(ScandidatePercent, '#0.0%')" />)
        </th>
        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">
            <xsl:param name="cellCount" select="100 * round($candidatePercent" />
            <xsl:param name="party" select="$candidateParty" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="drawCells">
      <xsl:param name="cellCount" />
      <xsl:param name="party" />
      <xsl:if test="$cellCount > 0">
         <td class="{$party}"></td>
         <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">
            <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="$cellCount - 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="party" select="$party" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML doc is far too long, and basically just contains names and votes. Anyone please offer some guidance? Thank you.

**ORIGINAL XSL:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- New Perspectives on XML, 3rd Edition Tutorial 6 Case Problem 1 Voter Web Style Sheet Author: Date: Filename: election.xsl Supporting Files: -->

-<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" method="html"/>


-<xsl:template match="/">


-<html>


-<head>

<title>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</title>

<link type="text/css" href="vwstyles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>


-<body>


-<div id="wrap">


-<header>

<img alt="Voter Web" src="vwlogo.png"/>

</header>

<h1>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</h1>


-<section id="votingResults">

<xsl:apply-templates select="congressResults/district"/>

</section>

</div>

</body>

</html>

</xsl:template>


-<xsl:template match="district">


-<h2>
District 
<xsl:value-of select="@dNumber"/>

</h2>


-<table class="electionTable">


-<thead>


-<tr>

<th>Candidate</th>

<th>Votes</th>

</tr>

</thead>


-<tbody>

<xsl:apply-templates select="candidates/candidate"/>

</tbody>

</table>

</xsl:template>


-<xsl:template match="candidate">

<tr> </tr>

</xsl:template>


-<xsl:template name="drawCells">

<xsl:param name="cellCount"/>

<xsl:param name="party"/>


-<xsl:if test="$cellCount > 0">

<td class="{$party}"/>


-<xsl:call-template name="drawCells">

<xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="$cellCount - 1"/>

<xsl:with-param name="party" select="$party"/>

</xsl:call-template>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: 1. post the source document. 2. how are you viewing the results? in a web browser? look at the source directly and see if there are any clues. "looks horrid" is really not a sufficient explanation for anyone to have any clue what the problem is.

Comment: Provide a simolified example. What's a basic input document, what do you want to see as output, what are you seeing instead.

Comment: Edited with the XML document. The result should be a Web page with an American flag logo, the candidate names, votes, results, etc.

Comment: And yes, I was using a Web browser to view the result document, sorry.

Comment: Can someone please provide any tips at all? Please...?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your "candidates.xml" file too, please? Also, you  say your XSLT is error free, but there are some errors in it. For example, to calculate `totalVotes`, you do `<xsl:variable name="totalVotes" select="sum(..//votes" />`. If you notice, there is a missing closing bracket for the sum function. Ideally, we'd like to copy your XML and XSLT into http://xsltransform.net/ (when it is working) and see the results for ourselves. Thank you!

Comment: I added a link to my dropbox folder with the XML file, because it is very large. Here is another link just in case: https://www.dropbox.com/s/awxrf8iu5g3fv32/congress.xml?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution. If you are using a browser as your tranform engine, link to a local copy of Saxon CE. For the sake of brevity, I have embedded the candidate data into the stylesheet. I leave it up to the OP to make the minor adjustments to have the candidate data loaded from an external document instead.

**Input document**

```
<congressResults>
   <district dNumber="1">
      <candidates>
         <candidate candidateID="DFL1">
            <votes precinct="ADAMS" precinctID="0005">263</votes>
            <votes precinct="ADAMS TWP." precinctID="0010">181</votes>
            <votes precinct="ADRIAN" precinctID="0005">349</votes>
            <votes precinct="CITY OF COURTLAND" precinctID="0020">195</votes>
         </candidate>
         <candidate candidateID="DFL2">
            <votes precinct="ADAMS" precinctID="0005">363</votes>
            <votes precinct="ADAMS TWP." precinctID="0010">281</votes>
            <votes precinct="ADRIAN" precinctID="0005">1</votes>
            <votes precinct="CITY OF COURTLAND" precinctID="0020">200</votes>
         </candidate>
      </candidates>
   </district>
</congressResults>
```

** XSLT 2.0 Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="bar-chart-width-for-100pct-votes" select="500" />

<xsl:variable name="candidate-info">
  <candidate candidateID="DFL1">
    <name>Sean</name>
    <party>red-party</party>
  </candidate>
  <candidate candidateID="DFL2">
    <name>John</name>
    <party>blue-party</party>
  </candidate>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="congressResults">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</title>
  <link href="vwstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <img src="http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/sites/default/files/styles/logo-thumbnail/public/0022/7347/brand.gif?itok=CiI8BEGj" />
    <h1>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="district">
    <section>
      <h2>District <xsl:value-of select="@dNumber" /></h2>
      <xsl:variable name="total-votes" select="sum(candidates/candidate/votes)" />
      <p><xsl:value-of select="$total-votes" /> votes in total for district <xsl:value-of select="@dNumber" /></p>
      <table class="vote-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="name-col">Candidate</th>
            <th colspan="3">Votes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="candidates/candidate">
            <xsl:with-param name="total-votes" select="$total-votes" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="candidate">
  <xsl:param name="total-votes" />
  <xsl:variable name="candidate" select="$candidate-info/candidate[@candidateID eq current()/@candidateID]" />
  <xsl:variable name="votes"     select="sum(votes)" />  
  <tr>
    <xsl:if test="(position()) mod 2 eq 0">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">alt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$candidate/name" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number( $votes, '###,##0')" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number( $votes div $total-votes, '#,##0.0000%')" /></td>
            <td style="padding: 5px;">
              <div class="{$candidate/party} logo"/>
              <div class="{$candidate/party} chart" style="width:{ round($votes div $total-votes * $bar-chart-width-for-100pct-votes)}px;" />
            </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**... yields result ...**

```css
/* vwstyles.css */
.logo {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.chart {
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;        
}

.red-party.chart {
  background-color: indianred;    
}

.blue-party.chart {
  background-color: steelblue;    
}

.red-party.logo {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=f55037417ca7155882f8bca641c8c8bb');
}

.blue-party.logo {
  background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/69d49d43101b3ba3adb7e53d23369551?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG');
}

.vote-table {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.vote-table td, #customers th {
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #98bf21;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}

.vote-table th {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #A7C942;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.vote-table tr.alt td {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #EAF2D3;
}

.name-col {
  width: 150px;   
}    
    
.number-col {
  width: 50px;   
}    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</title>
      <link href="vwstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body><img src="http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/sites/default/files/styles/logo-thumbnail/public/0022/7347/brand.gif?itok=CiI8BEGj"><h1>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</h1>
      <section>
         <h2>District 1</h2>
         <p>1833 votes in total for district 1</p>
         <table class="vote-table">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th class="name-col">Candidate</th>
                  <th colspan="3">Votes</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>Sean</td>
                  <td>988</td>
                  <td>53.9007%</td>
                  <td style="padding: 5px;">
                     <div class="red-party logo"></div>
                     <div class="red-party chart" style="width:270px;"></div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="alt">
                  <td>John</td>
                  <td>845</td>
                  <td>46.0993%</td>
                  <td style="padding: 5px;">
                     <div class="blue-party logo"></div>
                     <div class="blue-party chart" style="width:230px;"></div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sadly, Saxon is not working for me, so I usually use a site that my instructor linked me to. Also, the assignment requires me to just finish the XSL (I did not create the XML file nor most of the style sheet-- only the variables and parameters in the "candidate" template at the bottom.) I appreciate your help, I will examine your style sheet to try to fix my errors.

Comment: @Pau808 I hope it was not your instructor who created the stylesheet! It is not very good. Tip: The simplest way to create a bar chart is to use a <div> with coloured background, and with width and height driven by the data. Trying to create a bar chart with a variable number of <td>'s is a bit nutty. Also if this is an academic exercise, you should be able to use http://xsltransform.net/, and not be limited by XSLT version.

Comment: Most of the stylesheet came from the book/course as an exercise, but here is what the book asked me to do:

1. Create global var "candidateInfo"
2. Link XSL to "congress.xml"
3. Scroll down to the "candidate" template and create these local variables: a. candidateVotes, b. totalVotes, c. candidatePercent, d. candidateName, and e. candidateParty... Then I added the html code/th stuff "candidateName (candidateParty)" and "candidateVotes (candidatePercent)" and the "drawCells" table data and its parameters (cellCount and party)

Not asking anyone to do my homework, but pls help

Comment: How much of the textbook solution are you constrained to use, and how much are you allowed to vary? Are you constrained to XSLT 1.0 by the question or instructions? Or are you only constrained by the fact that you could not get Saxon to work?

Comment: Maybe list the actual textbook stylesheet, so we can see what we are allowed to change, and what is fixed by the question.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am limited to XSLT 1.0 and all I need to do is edit the style sheet then load the result doc (congress.xml) in my browser to watch it transform. As far as I know, I am not certain if or how much I can work around it, sadly. I usually follow the book, even though at my CC, some books are pretty much outdated. Edited with original/unedited XSL doc. BTW, I absolutely appreciate your help dearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem from my xml class. The solution is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!--
   New Perspectives on XML, 3rd Edition
   Tutorial 6
   Case Problem 1

   Voter Web Style Sheet
   Author: Nicholas English
   Date:   4/16/2018
   Filename:         election.xsl
   Supporting Files: 
-->

<!-- Style and output declaration. -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<!-- The candidate info variable. -->
<xsl:variable name="candidateInfo" select="document('candidates.xml')/candidates/candidate" />

<!-- Display the header. -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <!-- Page head. -->
        <head>
            <!-- Page title. -->
            <title>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</title>

            <!-- Include styles to make it look pretty. -->
            <link href="vwstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>

        <!-- Page body. -->
        <body>
            <div id="wrap">
                <!-- Page header. -->
                <header>
                    <!-- Include the logo. -->
                    <img src="vwlogo.png" alt="Voter Web" />
                </header>

                <!-- Site header text. -->
                <h1>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</h1>

                <!-- Voting results -->
                <section id="votingResults">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="congressResults/district" />

                </section>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Display template for each district. -->
<xsl:template match="district">

    <!-- District number. -->
    <h2>District <xsl:value-of select="@dNumber" /></h2>

    <!-- The candidates for each district. -->
    <table class="electionTable">

        <thead>
            <!-- The header texts. -->
            <tr>
                <th>Candidate</th>
                <th>Votes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <!-- Get the candidates information. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="candidates/candidate" />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<!-- The candidate template. -->
<xsl:template match="candidate">

    <!-- Local variables. -->
    <xsl:variable name="candidateVotes" select="sum(votes)" />
    <xsl:variable name="totalVotes" select="sum(..//votes)" />
    <xsl:variable name="candidatePercent" select="$candidateVotes div $totalVotes" />
    <xsl:variable name="candidateName" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/name" />
    <xsl:variable name="candidateParty" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/party" />

    <tr>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="$candidateName" />
            (<xsl:value-of select="$candidateParty" />)
        </th>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($candidateVotes, '###,##0')" />
            (<xsl:value-of  select="format-number($candidatePercent, '#0.0%')" />)
        </th>
        <td>

            <!-- Call draw cell template. -->
            <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">

                <!-- Draw the cells. -->
                <xsl:with-param name="party" select="$candidateParty" />
                <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="round(100 * $candidatePercent)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<!-- The draw cells template. -->
<xsl:template name="drawCells">
    <!-- Set params. -->
    <xsl:param name="cellCount" />
    <xsl:param name="party" />

    <!-- Count the cells -->
    <xsl:if test="$cellCount > 0">
        <td class="{$party}"></td>

        <!-- The cell template. -->
        <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">

            <!-- The cell template params. -->
            <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="$cellCount - 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="party" select="$party" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- End of file. -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The reason why your code did not work.

> `sum(..//votes` needs to be `sum(..//votes)` 
>   `sum($candidateVotes) div count($totalVotes)` needs to be `$candidateVotes div $totalVotes` 
>   `format-number(candidateVotes, '###,##0')` needs to be `format-number($candidateVotes, '###,##0')` 
>   `format-number(ScandidatePercent, '#0.0%')` needs to be `format-number($candidatePercent, '#0.0%')` 
>   `100 * round($candidatePercent` needs to be `round(100 * $candidatePercent)` 
>   `xsl:param` needs to be `xsl:with-param`